# Randomized Quick Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I have written the following code for randomized quicksort. This selects a random indexed element as the pivot_item in the partition function. Whenever i run the code, p is being set as either 0 or 1 only and not all the indexes from 0 to n-1 like it should be. You can verify this by removing `COMMENT 1` Why is this happening and how can i fix this?

Also, the array is being sorted properly only after the index 1 as you can see in the output. Why is this and how can i fix this?

My last problem is that no matter how many times i run the program, i get the same elements in the array to start off with. Isn't rand() supposed to generate new random numbers every time? So why am i getting the same array to be sorted every time? How can i fix this?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int partition(int low,int high,int a[])
{
int p=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int index=rand()%p+0;
//COMMENT 1       cout<<endl<<index<<"----"<<endl;
int temp1=a[index];
a[index]=a[low];
a[low]=temp1;
int left,right,pivot_item=a[low];
left=low;
right=high;

while(left<right)
{
while(a[left]<=pivot_item)
left++;
while(a[right]>pivot_item)
right--;
if(left<right)
{
int temp=a[right];
a[right]=a[left];
a[left]=temp;
}
}
a[low]=a[right];
a[right]=pivot_item;
return right;
}

void quicksort(int low,int high,int a[])
{
int pivot;
if(low<high)
{
pivot=partition(low,high,a);
quicksort(low,pivot-1,a);
quicksort(pivot+1,high,a);
}
}

int main()
{
int n;
n=50;
int a[n];
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
a[i]=rand()%60;

quicksort(0,n-1,a);
cout<<endl;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
cout<<a[i]<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
59
55
0
2
6
2
7
7
2
9
9
9
8
1
11
12
18
16
29
23
19
16
13
22
27
27
30
31
29
33
37
21
38
42
35
42
43
44
44
46
46
46
50
50
43
52
55
55
53
57
```

Comment: why not to use **rand() % (high - low)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [initialize the srand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once) in the main, e.g. with `srand(time(NULL))`, to get a decent random. If you don't do this, you'll get the same "random" sequence on each run of the program. (You'll have to `#include <time.h>` for this.)

Second, as pointed out in the comments, you should choose the pivot with

```
index = low + (rand() % (high - low));
```

This is because the size of the subarray for which you're choosing the pivot is `high-low+1`, which in general is different from the size of the original array (which is what you seemed to try to compute with the `sizeof` magic).

**Update.** As pointed out by Pete Becker, it might be a good idea to not use `srand` in the early stages of development (for the purposes of debugging). However,  it goes without saying that it's critical that you use `srand` if you want *randomized* quicksort.

Comment: Getting the same "random" sequence on each run of the program is critical to debugging. I **never** use `srand` in the first stages of developing a program. It comes later, when the fundamental logic has been correctly implemented.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's a very good point. But given that there were trouble choosing pivot uniformly at random, I thought it made sense to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Common problem, you are not getting the size of the actual array to be sorted:

```
int partition(int low,int high,int a[]) // a is just a pointer!
{
    int p=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); // size of pointer/size of element
```

You will need to pass in the size of the array. This is why that `sizeof` trick is awful. Instead, you could use:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
size_t array_size(T (&)[N])
{ return N; }
```

Then applying `array_size(a)` will give you a compiler error, since `a` is not an array. This construct appears in many libraries (probably boost, will paste a link here once I check), and will be in The Standard in [C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

There are also [better facilities for generating random numbers here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), and [here for a good explanation why `rand()` is bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY).